# Output not satisfactory in C program due to scanf function

Tags: c

I am executing this program. But on running this program, first it asks " Enter the Number of Test Cases" and after that i enter the number of test cases . but even after entering the number of test cases the cursor again is in state of asking an input from user. I don't know that after giving the number of test cases as input why is it asking for another input . Any help will be very grateful?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{ 
   int i,N;
   char * arr[N];
   printf("Enter the Number of Test Cases\n");
   scanf("%d \n",&N);
   printf("Enter the string\n");

   for(i=0;i<N;i++)
   { 
      arr[i]= (char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
      scanf(" %s ",arr[i]);
   }
   for(i=0;i<N;i++)
   {
      printf("The Enter String : %s \n",arr[i]);
   }
   for(i=0;i<N;i++)
   { 
      free(arr[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Thanks friends for discussing this question. I got the answer and the real problem is with the scanf function. I got a nice link to read about this problem. Hope you like it.
   http://c-faq.com/stdio/gets_flush2.html

Comment: Just as a sidenote: You cannot define `char * arr[N]` on the stack if `N` only gets read during _runtime_! The size of the stack is determined when compiling and thus you cannot store this array on the stack, you have to allocate memory the same way you do for the individual elements.

Comment: Get rid of the junk on the `scanf()` formats, you are asking to read spaces and newline around the data to be entered.

Comment: That could be an answer @javex.

Comment: @javex: C99 permits variable length arrays, and apparently user3401108 is using such a compiler.  However, it's not valid to do what has been done here: have a declaration like `char * arr[N];` before `N` is initialized with the desired value.

Comment: @javex: I changed the arr[N] to arr[100] so that compiler allocates the memory for array in stack at compile time but still the same problem persists.

Comment: not sure why javex comment is getting 6 upvotes,  this construct has been standard C for 15 years now

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `scanf` statement

```
scanf("%d \n",&N);
```

Please remove the `' '` and the `'\n'` and it will work

```
scanf("%d",&N);
```

Also,

```
char * arr[N];
```

does not work the way you want. A better solution would be.

```
char **arr = NULL;
/* get input for N */
arr = malloc(N * sizeof(char *));
```

Comment: char *arr[N]; is fine in principle.  It just needs to be moved after the scanf call which reads N.

Comment: They're officially called "variable length arrays" (VLAs for short), if you want to read up.

Comment: @NigelHarper: i tried it before posting the question here but still the same problem was there. I am using gcc compiler

Comment: @user3401108 may be u have to tell `gcc` using `-std=c99`

Comment: @user3401108 Your primary problem is almost certainly in the scanf calls as others have said. However the place you're declaring arr is still wrong. It's the nastiest kind of wrong because it doesn't cause an error and may appear to work.  

In actual fact I'd expect gcc to give you a warning for using N uninitialised - if it doesn't you may want to look at turning up the warning level (to -Wall at least).

Comment: @linuxdeveloper:even after using -Wall command no warning is there. I think something very basic to C programming is missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should verify your arr[N] because you are creating a static array with a size of N which isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about string formatting in scanf [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

I think what you really intended to use was:

```
scanf("%d", &N);
```

Just a heads up on something else wrong with the code. You are using an uninitialized value (N) when declaring your array:

```
  char * arr[N];
```

You may want to have a look at that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited  this code after getting the N value then declare the array of pointer else junk value assigned

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{ 
  int i,N;
  printf("Enter the Number of Test Cases\n");
  scanf("%d",&N);
  char *arr[N-1];
  printf("Enter the string\n");
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  { 
    arr[i]= (char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s",arr[i]);
   }
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
    printf("The Enter String : %s \n",arr[i]);
  }
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  { 
    free(arr[i]);
  }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several small changes you need to make to the program:

- fix how the `arr[]` array is allocated. Move the declaration of `arr[]` to after the `scanf("%d",&N);` that initializes `N`.
- change `scanf("%d \n",&N);` to `scanf("%d",&N);`
- change `scanf(" %s ",arr[i]);` to `scanf("%s",arr[i]);`

In my opinion `scanf()` isn't a great way to parse interactive input - it's too difficult to detect and handle minor variations on how someone might type in text.  `scanf()` might be fine for for test/demo programs or programs that are expected to deal with data files that have a rather well-defined, fixed format.

Anyway, what's happening in your program as posted is that the `scanf()` calls are getting stuck matching runs of whitespace in the input stream.  So if you remove that whitespace from your format specs, the program behaves more like you expect it to.